# Problem with Click Events in My Branching Logic

Tags: javascript, html, css

#### I have a module that contains branching logic. The 'click' events are not happening in the order I would like.

The expected behavior is that a **Question** renders and waits for a *click* event. Depending on the *click*, a different behavior occurs. These *click* events are supposed to happen based on which **Question** is currently rendered onscreen. After running the debugger, I discovered what happens is that no matter which **Question** is rendered onscreen, the *click* event that fires always happens inside `loadQuestion1()`.

**How do I get a *click* event to leave the function - `loadQuestion1()` - move into the next function - `loadQuestion2()`, `loadQuestion3()` - and listen for a *click* event there?**

*Let me know if you require the CSS. It didn't seem necessary to answer the question.*

```
<body>
  <div onload="loadModule">
    <div class="scene">
      <div id="o1" class="object object-square"></div>
      <div id="o2" class="object object-circle"></div>
      <div id="o3" class="object object-triangle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-div"></div>
  </div>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
const loadModule = () => {
  console.log('Module loaded!')

  const messageDiv = document.querySelector(".message-div");
  const object1 = document.querySelector("#o1");
  const object2 = document.querySelector("#o2");
  const object3 = document.querySelector("#o3");

  const questions = {
    q1: `I spy something that rhymes with <em><strong>bug</strong></em>. Can you find it?`,
    q2: `I spy something that rhymes with <em><strong>willow</strong></em>. Can you spot anything?`,
    q3: `I spy something that starts with an <em><strong>lll</strong></em> sound. Can you find one?`
  };
  const responses = {
    res1: `Yes, <em><strong>rug</strong></em> rhymes with <em><strong>bug</strong></em>!`,
    res2: `Yes, <em><strong>pillow</strong></em> rhymes with <em><strong>willow</strong></em>!`,
    res3: `Yes, lamp starts with an <em><strong>lll</strong></em> sound!`,
    res4: `Try again.`
  };

  const addMessage = (message) => {
    const p = document.createElement("P");
    p.classList.add("message", "animate-text");
    p.innerHTML = `${message}`;
    messageDiv.appendChild(p);
  };

  const selectRemoveMessage = () => {
    const message = document.querySelector(".message");
    message.remove();
  };

  // Question 1
  const loadQuestion1 = () => {
    addMessage(questions.q1);

    object1.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selectRemoveMessage();
      addMessage(responses.res1);
      setTimeout(() => {
        selectRemoveMessage();
        loadQuestion2();
      }, 5000); // turn this into a button instead
    });

    object2.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selectRemoveMessage();
      addMessage(responses.res4);
      setTimeout(() => {
        selectRemoveMessage();
        loadQuestion1();
      }, 3000);
    });

    object3.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selectRemoveMessage();
      addMessage(responses.res4);
      setTimeout(() => {
        selectRemoveMessage();
        loadQuestion1();
      }, 3000);
    });
  };

  // Question 2
  const loadQuestion2 = () => {
    addMessage(questions.q2);

    object1.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selectRemoveMessage();
      addMessage(responses.res4);
      setTimeout(() => {
        selectRemoveMessage();
        loadQuestion2();
      }, 3000);
    });

    object2.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selectRemoveMessage();
      addMessage(responses.res2);
      setTimeout(() => {
        selectRemoveMessage();
        loadQuestion3();
      }, 5000); // turn this into a button instead
    });

    object3.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selectRemoveMessage();
      addMessage(responses.res4);
      setTimeout(() => {
        selectRemoveMessage();
        loadQuestion2();
      }, 3000);
    });
  };

  // Question 3
  const loadQuestion3 = () => {
    addMessage(questions.q3);

    object1.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selectRemoveMessage();
      addMessage(responses.res4);
      setTimeout(() => {
        selectRemoveMessage();
        loadQuestion3();
      }, 3000);
    });

    object2.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selectRemoveMessage();
      addMessage(responses.res4);
      setTimeout(() => {
        selectRemoveMessage();
        loadQuestion3();
      }, 3000);
    });

    object3.addEventListener("click", () => {
      selectRemoveMessage();
      addMessage(responses.res3);
      // break;
    });
  };

  loadQuestion1();
};

loadModule();
```

Comment: Adding a new event listener does not remove previously added ones. Adding a secondary click listener will cause both click handler functions to run. (Also note that `p.innerHTML = \`${message}\`;` is nonsense, you can use `p.innerHTML = message;`)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has *lots* of repeating sections which I strongly recommend you reduce. Because there's so much it's hard to give you an exact answer, so instead here's as much related information as I can muster.

Just like you can create an event listener `element.addEventListener(...)` you can also remove one:

```js
// your click function
const loadFunction = () => {
  selectRemoveMessage();
  addMessage(responses.res1);
  setTimeout(() => {
    selectRemoveMessage();
    loadQuestion2();
  }, 5000); // turn this into a button instead
};

const loadQuestion1 = () => {
  addMessage(questions.q1);

  // add the click listener
  object1.addEventListener("click", loadFunction);
};

const unloadQuestion1 = () => {
  // remove the click listener
  object1.removeEventListener("click", loadFunction);
};
```

With this in mind I recommend that your code removes the previous listeners at the same time as adding the next ones.

Comment: I refactored things to be less repetitive as you suggested and added removeEventListener(). Everything seems to be working now, so thank you! I had to break each Question out into it's own separate function, which I'm sure could be refactored again, but this is good for now. I'll post the finished code below.